# AngularJS (with John Papa Styleguide) + RequireJS

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I'm working with angular for some time now, especially with John Papa's styleguide. But I'm still not sure if I understand it correctly, especially regarding the file structure with one item per file.

I tried doing that in a project with requireJS combined with angularJS, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work...

Some Background regarding the application:

It is a multimodule-application with **one main.js and app.js**. Every module is being developed in its own maven-module with a small java-backend and its own url-context. Right now all submodules are being refered in the main.js -> require.config.path e.g.

**main.js:**

```
require.config({
    // Paths to vendor scripts and separate files.
    paths: {
        'myModule': '../../mymodule/mymodule',
        'myOtherModule': '../../myothermodule/myothermodule',
         ... // many more angular modules
    },
    // Create shims for vendor libraries that aren't AMD modules and specify dependencies for them.
    shim: {
        'angular': {deps: ['jquery'], exports: 'angular'},
        'angularEN': {deps: ['angular'], exports: 'angularEN'},
        'angularDE': {deps: ['angular'], exports: 'angularDE'},
        'angularCH': {deps: ['angular'], exports: 'angularCH'},
        'ngResource': {deps: ['angular'], exports: 'ngResource'},
        'ngCookies': {deps: ['angular'], exports: 'ngCookies'},
        'angularRoute': ['angular'],
        'jquery': {exports: '$'},
        'jquery_cookie': ['jquery'],
        'hammer': ['jquery'],
        'materializeClockpicker': ['materialize'],
        'materialize': {deps: ['jquery', 'hammer']},
        'angularMaterialize': ['materialize'],
        'moment': {exports: 'moment'},
        'angularMoment': ['moment'],
        'foundation': ['jquery'],
        'ngTable': {deps: ['angular', 'jquery'], exports: 'ngTable'},
        'nvd3': {deps: ['d3'], exports: 'nvd3'},
        'angularnvd3': {deps: ['angular', 'nvd3'], exports: 'angular-nvd3'},
        'ngSanitize': {deps: ['angular'], exports: 'ngSanitize'},
        'ocLazyLoad': {deps: ['angular'], exports: 'ocLazyLoad'},
        'uiRouter': {deps: ['angular'], exports: 'uiRouter'},
        'ncyangularbreadcrumb': {deps: ['angular'], exports: 'ncyangularbreadcrumb'},
        'treeControl': {deps:['angular'], exports:'treeControl'},
        'ngAnimate': {deps: ['angular'], exports: 'ngAnimate'},
        'ngMap': {deps:['angular'], exports:'ngMap'},
        'angularFileSaver': {deps: ['angular', 'fileSaver', 'blob'], exports: 'angularFileSaver'},
        'nliMenu': {deps:['angular','treeControl'],exports:'nliMenu'},
        'mmFoundationTpls': {deps: ['angular'], exports: 'mmFoundationTpls'},
        'adf': {deps:['mmFoundationTpls', 'sortable'],exports:'adf'},
        'adfBase': {deps:['adf'],exports:'adfBase'},
        'localStorage': {deps: ['angular'], exports: 'localStorage'},
        'angularUiTree': {deps: ['angular'], exports: 'angularUiTree'},
        'angularRecaptcha': {deps: ['angular'], exports: 'angularRecaptcha'}
    },
    // kick start application
    deps: ['../../core/js/bootstrap']
```

**bootstrap.js:**

```
define([
    'require',
    'angular',
    'app',
    'app.config',
    'app.run',
    'app.controllers',
    'jquery',
    'foundation',
    'modernizr'
], function (require, angular) {
    'use strict';

    require(['domReady!'], function (document) {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myAwesomeApplication']);
    });
});
```

**app.js:**

```
define([
        'angular',
        'app.controllers',
        'app.config',
        'app.run',
        'appServices',
        'appFilters',
        'appDirectives',
        'angularRoute',
        'ngResource',
        'angularnvd3',
        'ngSanitize',
        'uiRouter',
        'uiRouterExtras',
        'offscreenMenu',
        'ncyangularbreadcrumb',
        'angularFileSaver',
        'treeControl',
        'angularUiTree',
        'adf',
        'adfBase',
        'dashboardPersistence',
        'mmFoundationTpls',
        'localStorage',
        'ngMap',
        'ngTable',
        'ngAnimate',
        'angularMaterialize',
        'materializeClockpicker',
        'angularMoment',

        /*Custom services*/
        'lang',
        'templatingUtils',
        'appUtils',
        'resetUtils',
        'passwordPolicyUtils',
        'nliConnector',
        'nliCaptcha',
        'nliMessages',
        'menuUtils',
        'nliMasterData',
        'validationUtils',
        'messagingUtils',
        'uiCoreServices',
        'angularRecaptcha',
        'cacheUtils',

        //... many more

        'myModuleModule',
        'myOtherModule'
    ],
    function (angular, appControllers, appConfig, appRun) {
        return angular
            .module('portals.nli', [
                'smo.controllers',
                'gkp.services',
                'gkp.filters',
                'gkp.directives',
                'adf',
                'adf.structures.base',
                'adf.nli.persistence',
                'ct.ui.router.extras',
                'fileSaver',
                'LocalStorageModule',
                'mm.foundation',
                'ncy-angular-breadcrumb',
                'ngAnimate',
                'ngMap',
                'ngResource',
                'ngRoute',
                'ngSanitize',
                'ngTable',
                'nvd3',
                'ui.router',
                'ui.tree',
                'treeControl',
                'ui.materialize',
                'angularMoment',

                /* Custom Services */
                'portals.nli.appUtils',
                'portals.nli.resetUtils',
                'portals.nli.captcha',
                'portals.nli.connector',
                'portals.nli.lang',
                'portals.nli.messagingUtils',
                'portals.nli.passwordPolicyUtils',
                'portals.nli.templatingUtils',
                'portals.nli.uiCoreServices',
                'portals.nli.validationUtils',
                'vcRecaptcha',
                'portals.nli.cacheUtils',

                'mymodule',
                'myothermodule'
        ])

        .constant(
            'APP_CONSTANTS', {
             ...
            }
        )

        .constant('Modernizr', Modernizr)

        .value('APP_VALUES', {
            ...
        })

        .config(appConfig)

        .run(appRun);
    });
})();
```

e.g. one of the sub-modules in this application looks like this:

```
/mymodule
    /mymodule.js
    /mymodule.config.js
    /mymodule.controller.js
```

**mymodule.js:**

```
define([
    'angular',
    'mymodule.config',
    'mymodule.controller'
],
function(angular) {
    'use strict';

    return angular
        .module('myModule', [])

        .constant('APP_CONSTANTS', {
            ...
        })

        .run('APP_CONSTANTS', function (APP_CONSTANTS) {
             ...  
        }]);
    });
```

**mymodule.config:**

```
define(['angular', 'mymodule'], function(angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myModule')
        .config(config);

    config.$inject=['$logProvider', '$stateProvider'];
    function config($logProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);

        $stateProvider
           ...
    }

    return config;
});
```

**mymodule.controller.js:**

```
define(['angular', 'mymodule'], function(angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myModule')
        .controller('MyModuleController', MyModuleController);

    MyModuleController.$inject=['$scope', '$log'];
    function MyModuleController($scope, $log) {
        var vm = this;

       /** ====================
        *   (Bindable) Members
        *  ==================== */
        vm.annualConsumption = null;
        vm.calorificVal = null;
        vm.zNumber = null;
        vm.checkValues = checkValues;
        vm.calculateGasConsumption = calculateGasConsumption;

       /** ========================
        *   Implementation Details
        *  ======================== */
        function checkValues() {
            return vm.annualConsumption && vm.calorificVal && vm.zNumber;
        }

        function calculateGasConsumption() {
            return vm.annualConsumption * vm.calorificVal * vm.zNumber;
        }
    }

    return MyModuleController;
});
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an exception on the console:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$injector/nomod?p0=myModule
    at angular.js?v=2017-03-15:78
    at angular.js?v=2017-03-15:1643
    at ensure (angular.js?v=2017-03-15:1567)
    at Object.module (angular.js?v=2017-03-15:1641)
    at mymodule.config.js?v=2017-03-15:6
    at Object.execCb (require233.js:1696)
    at Module.check (require233.js:883)
    at require233.js:630
    at each (require233.js:59)
    at breakCycle (require233.js:619)
```

Maybe you could take a look and tell me what's wrong? That would be so great, because I'm really having a hard time here. :-( I never had any problems with that when not using requireJS. I'm really starting to hate require....

Answer (score 0):

Edit the start of those files as below:

mymodule.js:

```
define([
    'angular',
],
```

mymodule.config:

```
define(['angular', 'mymodule'], function(angular,myModule) {
    myModule.config(config);
```

mymodule.controller:

```
define(['angular', 'mymodule'], function(angular,myModule) {
    myModule.controller('MyModuleController', MyModuleController);
```

And bootstrap it somewhere (such as index.js) as below:

```
requirejs(["mymodule","mymodule.config","mymodule.controller"],function(mymodule){
//bootstrap 'mymodule' by hand without "ng-app"
});
```

Comment: So if I see it correctly, you are not using the angular-getter for the module but calling the functions config and controller on the main-module-file?

Comment: @Vortilion exactly

Comment: Your way can also works, but not that clear after all. It's not the vial reason why your code doesn't work. The vial reason is that you "define" the config and the controller at the begining of the "mymodule" file.

Comment: I thought that's the purpose of require. I'm defining the "mymodule.js" in the main.js which also defines dependencies to its controller and config file. If I don't do that it doesn't load the files at all... I guess then I'd have to define them in the main.js and app.js at least. That's what I wanted to avoid, cause I thought it is the purpose of require.js that I don't have to reference every JS File for every submodule I have inside the main.js? Because If I do, I don't understand the purpose of requireJS at all. either I have all JS files in my index.html or I have them all in my main.js?

Comment: Actually u r right. But u should notice that angularjs has its own module management mechanism. It may break when you use it with other module mechanism. In requirejs's view, your my "myModule" depends on your config and controller, but angularjs don't think so.

Comment: Using requirejs has "scope" benefits.

Comment: Or u can use http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular so solve the problem. But it's somehow weird.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your angular mymodule.js like this:

```js
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    var ret = angular
        .module('myModule', [])
        .constant('APP_CONSTANTS', {

        })
        .run('APP_CONSTANTS', function (APP_CONSTANTS) {

        });

    requirejs(['mymodule.config', 'mymodule.controller'], function () {
        // do some bootstrap things
    });
    return ret;
});
```

And remove "mymodule"
dependences of your config and controller files.